# fopen not working on server with no errors

Tags: php

My code is working perfectly fine on local PHP instance (version 5.4.31) in a Windows environment.

But when I am running this same file on my server, it doesn't work
on the server (PHP version 5.4.16) in a Centos environment.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
//$myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");

if (!file_exists("file.txt")) { 
  die('File does not exist'); 
}

clearstatcache(); 
// $fh = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("can't open file");

$fh = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die($php_errormsg); 
$sql = fread($fh, filesize("file.txt")); 

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

?>
```

The problem is file is not getting generated, upon that I am unable to see error logs, where can I see errors so I can find solution accordingly?

Comment: so it does your code, then set the error reporting?

Comment: I have written `error_reporting(E_ALL);` am i doing it wrong ?

Comment: I'm not sure tbh, but I always set my reporting at the top of the file (not sure if it makes a difference, but it's worth a shot)

Comment: but it's normal you put the error_reporting under the code, put it above and it it shows  you

Comment: @user2828442 Regarding the Doc (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php), `E_WARN` is raised. so you have to put error_reporting on top of your file.

Plus side, there is more on the doc about windows, I encourage you to read it. :)

Comment: still same, it says File does not exist , file not generated, no error seen

Comment: @user2828442 that is the error, file doesn't exist

Comment: i forgot to tell you, SSL is enabled in there,is it a point of concern ?

Comment: @user2828442 Have you read the doc? Please, make sure your PHP settings are correctly configured. If Safe Mode, ensure the user `apache` or `www-data` have the rights on the folder.

Comment: let me check this right away and get back

Comment: system is not in safe mode, folder and file has permission 777, what else should i do ?

Comment: @user2828442 About the `fopen()` you have your `file.txt` in the root of your project? 

Check this: https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.open-basedir

_Limit the files that can be accessed by PHP to the specified directory-tree, including the file itself. This directive is NOT affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off._

Comment: Hi user2828442. Jut a quick reminder that quote blocks (using the > device) are only for quotes, and are not a general highlighter.

Answer (score 1):

Normally is like this :

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

//$myfile = fopen("testfile.txt", "w");
if (!file_exists("file.txt")) { die('File does not exist'); }
 clearstatcache(); 
// $fh = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die("can't open file");
$fh = fopen("file.txt", "r") or die($php_errormsg); 
 $sql = fread($fh,filesize("file.txt")); 

?>
```

`file.txt` should be in the same folder

```
┬root
  |
  |
  └─┬www
    |
    ├─ test4.php
    | 
    ├─ file.txt
    |
```

Comment: still same, it says `File does not exist` , file not generated, no error seen

Comment: whilst this helps with the error reporting, it's not an answer to the actual question :)

Comment: yeah, the reporting error works,  but are you sure you put your file in the same folder?

Comment: i forgot to tell you, SSL is enabled in there,is it a point of concern ?

Comment: show us the tree of your project, and the file where is it ?

Comment: Its in the root directory, u can access it here noproxy.in/test4.php

Comment: put your whole code in StackOverflow with your file and the content, it allows us to figure out what's happening.

Comment: Well, I can't access to your project ... by the way is your file file.txt has the right name file.txt? and is in the same folder as test4.php?

Comment: I added for you a small schema above